# MigraDoc Cell Background Colour Issues

Tags: c#, migradoc

I have created a table.  3 columns in the first row, 1 in the second (merge right 2) and 3 columns in the last row.
I am trying to set the background colour of the cells in the top and bottom rows, but it will only let me set the colour of the top-left cell??  However, if i increase the height of the table so it does not fit on a page, then the whole of the 3rd row is coloured correctly, but the first row only the first cell is correct!?!?

```
public static void CreateReport(Document report)
{
    var margin = Unit.FromMillimeter(5);
    var wrapperHeight = Unit.FromMillimeter(15);
    var wrapperWidth = Unit.FromMillimeter(60);
    var centralWidth = Unit.FromMillimeter(170);
    var mainHeight = Unit.FromMillimeter(169);

    report.DefaultPageSetup.Orientation = Orientation.Landscape;
    report.DefaultPageSetup.LeftMargin = 
    report.DefaultPageSetup.TopMargin =
    report.DefaultPageSetup.RightMargin = 
    report.DefaultPageSetup.BottomMargin = margin;

    report.AddSection();
    var layout = report.LastSection.AddTable();
    layout.Borders.Visible = true;

    var leftColumn = layout.AddColumn();
    leftColumn.Width = wrapperWidth;

    var centralColumn = layout.AddColumn();
    centralColumn.Width = centralWidth;

    var rightColumn = layout.AddColumn();
    rightColumn.Width = wrapperWidth;

    var topRow = layout.AddRow();
    topRow.Height = wrapperHeight;

    var middleRow = layout.AddRow();

    var bottomRow = layout.AddRow();
    bottomRow.Height = wrapperHeight;

    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
    {
        layout[0, column].Shading.Color = new Color(0x595959); // Works
        layout[0, column].Shading.Color = new Color(0x595959); // ??
        layout[0, column].Shading.Color = new Color(0x595959); // ??
        layout[2, column].Shading.Color = new Color(0x595959); // ??
        layout[2, column].Shading.Color = new Color(0x595959); // ??
        layout[2, column].Shading.Color = new Color(0x595959); // ??
    }

    layout[0, 0].Format.Font.Size = 31;
    layout[0, 0].Format.Font.Color = Colors.Blue;
    layout[0, 0].AddParagraph("TITLE");

    layout[0, 2].Format.Font.Size = 31;
    layout[0, 2].Format.Font.Color = Colors.Blue;
    layout[0, 2].AddParagraph("TITLE 2");

    middleRow.Height = mainHeight;
    middleRow.Cells[0].MergeRight = 2;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Upgraded to the latest Release Candidate - same issue (v1.50.4845-RC2a) - PDFsharp-MigraDoc-gdi

Comment: Are the colours correct when you create an RTF instead of PDF?

Comment: I changed the way i do it.  Made the whole of the page grey, then just made the central cell white.  thanks for your help.